# Сделать заголовок страницы в Laravel/vuejs приложении

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Всем привет,

В Laravel 5.5/vue.js2.5  приложении хочу сделать заголовок страницы в виде Application name : Page Title

Лайоут страниц приложения resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title id="app_title">@if( !empty($site_name) ){{ $site_name }}@endif</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
<div id="app">

    <app-header ></app-header>

    @yield('content')

    <status-line></status-line>
</div> <!-- id="app">-->

@include('layouts.footer')

<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js'    ) }}{{  "?dt=".time()  }}"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Все страницы запускаются через контейнер app/Http/Controllers/DashboardController.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

...
class DashboardController extends MyAppController
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->addVariablesToJS();
        $site_name  = Settings::getValue('site_name', '');
        return view('admin.dashboard.index',['site_name'=> $site_name]);
    }
...
```

“Application name”  хранится в базе данных и я его получаю и передаю в контролле выше и вставляю в 1ом скрипте.
Но так как контрол выше не знает когда происходит переход страниц роутера vuejs, то я сделал обращение к тексту заголовка в событии страницы:

```
  ...
    mounted() {
        alert( "mounted this.is_insert::"+(this.is_insert) )
       $("#app_title").html('Page Title')
  ...
```

app_title - это id заголовка в первом скрипте
Я использовал jquery-метод для доступа к заголовку приложения так как он находится вне блока работы vuejs:

```
<div id="app">

    <app-header ></app-header>

    @yield('content')

    <status-line></status-line>
</div> <!-- id="app">-->
```

И вопрос а можно ли тут исхитриться сделать средствами vuejs а не прибегать к  jquery?
Или сделать как-то иначе с организацией приложения?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Можно без jQuery: `document.title = 'Page title'`